# What does the array operator "-" (a hypen or a dash) mean and do in C?

Tags: c, arrays, shell, unix, operators

I am taking a course in operating systems and we were assigned the "Project 1 UNIX Shell and History Feature" as found in Abraham Silberschatz Operating Systems pg 157.  I was doing research on the problem and came across an interesting GitHub code.  It included an "else if" statement with an operator I've never seen before (a dash -).  I'm trying to find out what it does.
(link)https://github.com/deepakavs/Unix-shell-and-history-feature-C/blob/master/shell2.c

```
else if (args[0][0]-'!' ==0)
{   int x = args[0][1]- '0'; 
    int z = args[0][2]- '0';
```

as you can see in the two D array "ags[0][0]-'!'" and on "int x" and "int z"

Can someone tell me what this is called and what is it doing?

Thanks

Comment: It's a "minus"!

Comment: It's not an array operator; it's just a minus sign, subtracting the (ASCCI) value of `!` from whatever is stored in `args[0][0]`.

Comment: You men the *arithmetic minus operator*?

Comment: By the way, it would be much easier to read and understand if it was `if (args[0][0] == '!')`

Comment: (Ugh, I mean ASCII, not ASCCI.)

Comment: Thank you all very much.  I havn't seen this style of array assignment before and it was very confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`args[0][1] - '0'` is the idiomatic way of converting a `char` value which represents a digit to the numeric value of that digit. It works for *all encodings* supported by C.

`args[0][0] - '!' == 0` is a flashy way of testing if `args[0][0]` has the same value as `'!'`. The author has an idiosyncratic, perhaps quixotic, sense of symmetry: most folk would write `args[0][0] == '!'`.

Comment: All encodings? I always had the impression that this relationship was unique to ASCII.

Comment: @GovindParmar: No, C only supports encodings where 0 to 9 are consecutive. You're correct about alpha characters.

Comment: @GovindParmar It's required for digits, but not for any other character.

Comment: Personally I always write `args[0][0] == (!'!'??!'!')` to check if something is equal to `'!'`. Much flashier.

Comment: @Lundin Don't you use `/**/` instead of a space too?

Comment: @Bathsheba Nope, I use `#define SPACE(a,b) a b`.

Comment: Thank you all very much.  I havn't seen this style of array assignment before and it was very confusing.

Comment: @Bathsheba Just for clarity, in this code snippet "int x = args[0][1]- '0' " is it basically type casting from char to int?

Comment: @Bathsheba This is part of a program that builds a UNIX shell command interface.  The args would be commands inputted by the user, exp(ps, ls, history, etc...)

Comment: In which case that argument is converted to an int - ‘0’ is already an int.

Answer (score 2):

It's subtraction. `char` values are numeric too, and can be added, subtracted, multiplied, and divided from each other like any other numeric type.

What's specifically going on in your code is that the character set being used by your C compiler has some useful relations, like the textual representation of a digit is exactly `'0'`  higher than the actual numeric value for that digit, so subtracting `'0'` will give you the digit itself. This is true of all encodings supported by C.

The first comparison could just as easily have been `if(args[0][0] == '!')`, by the way.

Comment: "ASCII has some useful relations, like the textual representation of a digit is exactly '0' higher than the actual numeric value for that digit, so subtracting '0' will give you the digit itself." - this is true for all encodings supported by C.

Comment: Thank you. Have an upvote! Finally, I can't resist, note that `'0'` is an `int` type in C. (Cf. C++).

Comment: @Bathsheba Updated my answer to reflect what I learned a few seconds ago on your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the binary subtraction operator. A mathematical "minus" if you will.

In this specific case it is used to subtract the symbol value of `'0'` from a digit, to convert from symbolic to integer.

Comment: @Bathsheba Meh, well whatever encoding they happen to use. ASCII is most often referred to in school book examples.

Answer (score 0):

As characters are only numbers internally, `args[0][0] - '!' == 0` checks if the first character of the first argument equals `'!'`.
`args[0][1] - '0'` converts characters to their numerical value.